# Available Point-In-Time recovery points for AWS RDS instances

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-rds

I discovered that it is possible to rollback my DB instance to a certain point-in-time, via binary logging.

I can rollback to 5 minutes ago, but how do I see the previous PiT? Is this 10 minutes ago? What would happen if I select 7 minutes ago, would the binary logs of the two closest PiT merge?

A secondary question, is 35 days the longest retention period for automated backups? The list does not go further when modifying my DB instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I discovered that it is possible to rollback my DB instance to a certain point-in-time

That's the approximate net effect, but your description is not precisely correct.

What's possible with [Point-in-time Recovery](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html) is that you can create a **new** instance, with the data as it existed on your current instance, at the specified point in time.

Your current instance is not modified by this operation, so you're not actually rolling anything back.

Point-in-time allows you to specify any time >= the time of the first retained backup, and <= the "latest restorable time," which is approximately 5 minutes ago.

The binlogs are not "merged" when you specify an arbitrary time -- that's not how binary logging and restoration work.  The new instance is created with the latest snapshot that occurred prior to the specified time, and then the binary logs from that point in time up until the time you specified are applied, consecutively, to the instance, in order to roll it *forward* from the snapshot to the desired point in time.  Binlog entries after the specified point in time are simply not executed.

The end result is a new instance that represents the data on your instance as it existed at the specified point in time.

If you then want to actually replace the old RDS instance with the new one in your stack, you change the DB instance identifier on old (to something different) and new (to match the prior value from old) and the DNS entry is automatically updated so that your application can find the new instance at the old hostname.

---

Yes, 35 days is the longest retention period for automated backups.

> You can modify the backup retention period; valid values are 0 (for no backup retention) to a maximum of 35 days.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was all I needed to know.

Sorry for the late reply/acceptance, I was away until today.